# HTML input type date is sometimes retrun null value if i entered the button again

Tags: html, angular

HTML input type date is sometimes returned the null value if I entered the button again.1st time only it returned selected data value if I again enter the button it will return the null value .how to solve this problem?

```
      <form [formGroup]="CouponUsageForm" (ngSubmit)="couponlist(CouponUsageForm.value)">
          <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-12">
                  <div class="panel">
                      <div class="panel-body">                           
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                  <div class="form-group">
                                      <div class="col-sm-12">

                                          <select class="form-control" formControlName="couponType" style="margin-bottom:0px" (change)="GetCityList(t.value)"  required>
                                              <option value="">Select Coupon Type</option>
                                              <option value="1">Redeemable</option>
                                              <option value="0">Authentication</option>

                                          <div *ngIf="CouponUsageForm.controls['couponType'].invalid && (CouponUsageForm.controls['couponType'].dirty || CouponUsageForm.controls['couponType'].touched)">
                                          <div style="color:red" *ngIf="CouponUsageForm.controls['couponType'].errors.required">
                                                Coupon Type  is required.
                                              </div>
                                              </div>
                                      </div>
                                  </div>
                              </div>

                              <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">                                    
                                  <div class="col-sm-12">                                       
                                    <input type="date"formControlName="fromDate" [(ngModel)]="fromDate" value="fromDate" class="form-control" [max]="getToday()"> </div> </div> </div>
   <div class="col-md-3">     <div class="form-group">     <input type="date" formControlName="toDate"  [(ngModel)]="toDate" value="toDate" class="form-control" [max]="getToday()"> </div>  </div></div> </div>    <div class="row">
                              <div class="col-md-12" style="text-align: center; margin-top: 2%;">
                                  <div class="form-group">

                                          <button type="submit" [disabled]="!CouponUsageForm.valid" style="text-align:center;background-color: #009390" class="btn btn-success btn-rounded dropdown-toggle">
                                              <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true"></i> View Users
                                          </button>

                                  </div>
                              </div>
                            </div>

                      </div>

                      </div>
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>



      </form>
```

Comment: Try to use `[(ngModel)]="dateVar"` and set today date from component on this var.

Comment: post full code please.